# Why do we need client to test SOAP web services, but not for REST?

Tags: web-services

I am new to web services. I am studying it through various sites. Got confused for below query.

Why do we need client to test SOAP web services, but not for REST?

Thank You :)
Cheers!!!
Nitin

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "you don't **mandatory need** client to work with SOAP web services, and you **may wish** to use a client for ReST service".

Having a SOAP client makes things much simpler. In case of SOAP web service there's thing called WSDL, where your client can get all the information about this service - classes, operations, etc... all together called *service contract*. Based on this knowledge, a decent client will present you with user-friendly UI to make SOAP calls and display output. But, again, if you're skilled (and crazy) enough, you can do it even through `telnet` command.

The ReST is more general term. Actually SOAP web services can be referred to as *ReST level 0 services*. Since ReST is more general, by definition there are more general rules. For example, there's no common rule where to get service contract. On the other hand, ReST services nowadays are written the way that they can be simply consumed from e.g. JavaScript. This means that you can use tools like **Postman** or **DHC** Chrome extensions to make requests and see results - and they will work as a client to your ReST service.